# Ошибка сборки проекта в Qt Creator. No rule to make target moc.exe

Tags: qt, сборка, qmake

До этого проект собирался без проблем, сегодня запускаю Qt Creator, открываю проект и он не собирается, пишет такую ошибку:
`:-1: error: No rule to make target '../../../../Qt/5.9.1/mingw53_32/bin/moc.exe', needed by 'debug/moc_interface.cpp'.  Stop.`
Файла `moc.exe` у меня нет нигде, я поискал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил ошибку переустановкой mingw, moc файл появился